# Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat' after replace chinese

Tags: mysql, utf-8, concatenation

Before:

```
set extrainfo =concat('{"from":"carpool","table":"Block",  
"key_field":"b_index","key_value:"',b_index,'","infoid":"',info_id,'",
"code":"0","message":"This trip is valid"}');
```

run success.
I replaced "This trip is valid" with "行程符合规范" :

```
set extrainfo =concat( '{"from":"carpool","table":"Block","key_field":
"b_index","key_value:"',b_index,'","infoid":"',info_id,'",
"code":"0","message":"行程符合规范"}');
```

show me:

```
(node:30849) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): 
`enter code here`Error: ER_CANT_AGGREGATE_NCOLLATIONS: 
`enter code here`Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat'
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Code in MySQL Stored Procedures (MySQL 5.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Codes:

```
set extrainfo =concat( '{"from":"carpool","table":"Block","key_field":
   "b_index","key_value:"',convert(b_index,char),'","infoid":"',convert(info_id,char),'",
"code":"0","message":"行程符合规范"}');
```

replace b_index with convert(b_index,char). It works well.